# How to use Lookup function for obtaining values from two attributes?

Tags: reporting-services

If I have data set as under

[image]

I can use

```
=Lookup("Gap", Fields!Name.Value, Fields!value.Value, "DataSet1")
```

to obtain the Gap value :  761

now I have the below data set

[image]

and I want to obtain the "GAP" value for X-Bucket.

How will the LOOKUP function be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to use Multiple condition inside your lookup function.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Name.Value  & "1-30-Bucket",Fields!Name.Value & Fields!Bucket.Value ,Fields!value.Value,"DataSet4")
```

Note: for my Testing I used 1-30-Bucket rather than X-Bucket so that I do not return 1st value, you can updated the expression as required.

[image]

Comment: I have another requirement . Can you please help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751252/how-to-open-a-subreport-on-the-piechart-silce-click