# How to open a subreport on the piechart slice click?

Tags: reporting-services

Here is a report I am building:

[image]

If we click on the Blue section, then the GAP related report link will open. Likewise, if we click on the Orange section, the NC related report will open.

How to do it using SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add screenshots for Refrence, 
Step by step way to perform Pie chart.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

just click on data lables or simply numbers which are shown, then on Right hand side under properties you will see option and there you see Action. There you can choose go to Report and configure your reports.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the % values should be kind of hyperlinked so that whenever user clicks on the pie-slice, only the detail report for that particular section should be open

Comment: I have another requirement. Can you please find sometime to look into that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762591/how-to-display-image-using-image-control-inside-a-table-dynamically